# could not create dts.application because of error 0x80040154 dtexec error in SSIS

Tags: ssis, dtexec

Should the SSIS package execution work with `dtexec.exe` without installing integration services or SQL server?

Comment: No.  Integration Services needs to be installed and running on the server.